# Задать размер файлам при копирование в папку

Tags: c#

Необходимо при копирование файлов указать размер файлов, которые которые будут скопированы в папку.
Например мы задали **3 МБ** для каждого файла, нужно копировать все файлы не превышающие больше заданного размера.

Копирование файлов:

```
// массив расширений
string[] extens = 
{ 
 ".txt", ".doc", 
 ".ico", 
};
// копирование в папку
foreach (string fileName in Directory.GetFiles(Easy.GooVer, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
  string ext = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
  if (Array.IndexOf(extens, ext) >= 0)
  { 
    File.Copy(fileName, Path.Combine(Easy.str1, Path.GetFileName(fileName)), true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте [`DirectoryInfo`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.IO.DirectoryInfo?view=netframework-4.7) вместо [`Directory`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.IO.Directory?view=netframework-4.7):

```
// массив расширений
string[] extens =
{
    ".txt", ".doc",
    ".ico",
};

 const long limit = 3 * 1024 * 1024;

// копирование в папку
foreach (var file in new DirectoryInfo(Easy.GooVer).GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    string ext = file.Extension;

    if (extens.Contains(ext) && file.Length <= limit)
    {
        file.CopyTo(Easy.str1 + file.Name, overwrite:true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Вопрос: Пишу через другой класс этот пример, и хочу чтобы я мог добавлять нужный мне размер через `textbox`, Я так полагаю нужно сделать так:`void (TextBox t) { const long limit = t * 1024 * 1024; }` ?

Comment: @ArteS нет, передавать экземпляры контролов в методы - почти всегда плохая идея. Используйте свойство `Text` вашего текстбокса, преобразуя его строковое значение в `int`

Comment: можете привести пример данного свойства ?

Comment: @ArteS см. https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.text%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396