# Проверка на размер файла

Tags: c#

Есть код, который копирует файлы. Как добавить условие на размер файлов? Если размер файла более 300 кб, то копировать не надо.

```
static void Search(string sDir)
    {
        try
        {
            Directory.EnumerateFiles(sDir, "*.az")
             .AsParallel()
             .WithDegreeOfParallelism(2)
             .ForAll(d => File.Copy(d, Path.GetTempPath() + Path.GetFileName(d), true));

            foreach (string path in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(sDir))
                Search(path);
        }
        catch (System.Exception excpt)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: вес и размер чего вас интересуют?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Задать размер файлам при копирование в папку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/651599/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d1%83)

Answer (score 1):

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles(sDir, "*.az").Where(x => new FileInfo(x).Length <= 300 * 1024)...
```

Метод `Directory.EnumerateFiles` возвращает перечисление объектов типа `string` (путь к файлу). Создаем экземпляр класса `FileInfo`, который имеет свойство [Length](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.fileinfo.length(v=vs.110).aspx). На него и накладывается условие.